# A sentence after a comma without any explicit coordination conjunction, is it allowed?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

Consider this sentence from [Bill Gate's book](https://books.google.com/books?id=Sx50blsZuMoC&pg=PT74&dq=%22We%20had%20to%20build%20an%20Internet%20system%20that%20was%20so%20convenient,%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Kod2VYePC7aLsQS2oLzgCQ&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22We%20had%20to%20build%20an%20Internet%20system%20that%20was%20so%20convenient%2C%22&f=false) (Business @ the Speed of Thought: Using a Digital Nervous System)

> We had to build an internet system that was so convenient, customers got more value for their time than they did on the phone.

There are two full sentence after and before comma! Is it correct? isn't it better to be:

> We had to build an internet system that was so convenient, customers **getting** more value for their time than they did on the phone.

To make the second one ablative absolute? how do you analyze this sentence?

Comment: Grammatically it's a device often used. _It was so hot that people were fainting._ /  _It was so hot, people were fainting._ The comma is needed when the 'that' is deleted, to avoid garden-pathiness or even ambiguity. However, I don't think the logic is great in this example, pairing rather disparate concepts (so convenient that it was cheaper than ...). Convenient usually costs more.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there are 'two full sentences'. Would you consider *We had to build an internet system that was so convenient.* as a complete sentence?

However *We had to build an internet system* is a sentence. The relative pronoun *that* connects the important second clause. And it seems to me this is the pivot point.

Personally, I do not see the need for any punctuation. The *which*, *that* and the *than* are effectively doing the work of commas etc. But I might put a comma after *system*. I would say:

***We had to build an internet system, which was so convenient that customers could get more value for their time than they could on the phone.***

Comment: you mean: .... that was so convenient (that) customers could get .....? if you mean that there is a zero relative "that", so the the sentence in the book is puntuationally incorrect, isn't it?

Comment: I agree the comma is not obligatory, but I wouldn't call it wrong to include it. The elided _that_ makes for a (small) pause, which can be indicated by that comma. It's more of a style choice than grammar, of course.

Comment: as you know for so.....that..... construction it is not common to have zero relative! it seems that if the sentence is correct with that "," the ablative absolute structure would be a better choice! so you say that the "," is "that"? can you bring me a reference that that justify this position? thanks for your attention!

Comment: @oerkelens I think a comma is quite out of place there. I agree there should be a pause. But the comma seems to me to interrupt the thought's sequence. Better, in my view to include the currently elided *that*. To avoid having two *thats*, separated by only three words, I would probably change the first one to *which*.

Comment: @RootLopht: "as you know for so.....that..... construction it is not common to have zero relative! " No, I do not know that. "It rained so hard my house flooded" sounds like a completely normal sentence. I though so hard my head hurts, but I cannot see why it would be uncommon.

Comment: The comma does seem a bit awkward, I agree. I guess there are several ways to improve on this sentence — but hey, I doubt people read Bill Gates' book for the impressively fluent style and use of language...

Comment: @oerkelens A year ago I read a book by a very distinguished Social Psychologist who conducted an immensely interesting experiment. (I'll not mention his name). But the book is so long, and written with such verbosity, and in places in tortured English, that I felt sure many readers just gave up. I actually emailed the author offering to help him re-write it, and to my immense surprise I got a reply saying he would consider the offer when it came up for reprinting. I've not heard anything since!. Perhaps I should try that with Bill Gates!

Comment: @oerkelens so/that is one of the correlative subordinators and I have doubt that there is no problem with reduction of relative part! you can confer "Comparative clauses and other degree
complements" section in " Longman Grammar of Spoken and Written English" that has a corpus-based approach!

Comment: @RootLopht: I don't have access to that book, but it is a construction that is so common people use it all the time (oops, I did it _again_). I really wonder _what_ the "problem" would be with eliding _that_ in so..that...? Googling fro "so good it" gives plenty of examples of "so good it's bad" or "so bad it's good". And there are plenty more examples of usage.

Comment: @oerkelens you are completely right! we have so/(that) construction. I should apologize! English is not my first language.